# How to print the list twice by applying different keyitem before and after?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="area" style="height:200px;width:80%">
    1.2
    2.25
    25.3
</textarea>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<script>
function pad(num, diff) {
return diff > 0 ? pad(num, diff - 1) + 0 : num;
}

function processString(num) {
var tmp = num.replace(/\.+/g, '');
var diff = 4 - tmp.length;
var tmpl = '<key>#{padded}</key>'+'<string>#{padded}</string>';
var padded = diff > 0 ? pad(tmp, diff).split('').join('.') : num;
return tmpl.replace('#{padded}', padded);
}

var button = document.getElementById('submit');
button.addEventListener('click', processArea);

function processArea() {
var area = document.getElementById('area');
var arr = area.value.split(/\n/);
var header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM   
"file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">\n<plist   
version="1.0">\n<dict>\n<array>\n';
var footer = '\n</array>\n</plist>';
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  arr[i] = processString(arr[i]);
}
area.value = header+arr.join('\r\n')+footer;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM   
"file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<array>
<key>1.2.0.0</key><string>#{padded}</string>
<key>2.2.5.0</key><string>#{padded}</string>
<key>2.5.3.0</key><string>#{padded}</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM   
"file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<array>
<key>1.2.0.0</key>
<string>1.2.0.0</string>
<key>2.25.0.0</key>
<string>2.25.0.0</string>
<key>25.3.0.0</key>
<string>25.3.0.0</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Can any one help me please, how do i can achieve this output.

I want the entered list must be print twice with different prefix and post-fix as shown in expected output

But i am not able to get such output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's just js producing xml. you can print anything you want, anywhere...RTFM: [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). if you want to replace all instances in a string, you need to provide the `g` (global) flag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/20/

you can see this fiddle,how exactly my code works.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski i think you didn't got my query.

Your suggestion is not the solution.

Comment: I think no one can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

corrected your code and its working fine now.

```js
function pad(num, diff) {
  return diff > 0 ? pad(num, diff - 1) + 0 : num;
}

function processString(num) {
  var tmp = num.trim().replace(/\.+/g, '');
  var diff = 4 - tmp.length;
  var tmpl = '<key>#{padded}</key>' + '\n<string>#{padded}</string>';
  var padded = diff > 0 ? pad(tmp, diff).split('').join('.') : num;
  return tmpl.replace(/#{padded}/g, padded);
}

var button = document.getElementById('submit');
button.addEventListener('click', processArea);

function processArea() {
  var area = document.getElementById('area');
  var arr = area.value.trim().split(/\n/);
  var header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM' +
    '"file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">\n<plist ' +
    'version="1.0">\n<dict>\n<array>\n';
  var footer = '\n</array>\n</dict>\n</plist>';
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    arr[i] = processString(arr[i]);
  }
  area.value = header + arr.join('\r\n') + footer;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area" style="height:200px;width:80%">
  1.2 
  2.25 
  25.3
</textarea>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function pad(num, diff) {
return diff > 0 ? pad(num, diff - 1) + 0 : num;
}

function processString(num) {
var tmp = num.replace(/\.+/g, '');
var diff = 4 - tmp.length;
var tmpl = '<key>#{padded}</key>'+'<string>#{padded}</string>';
var padded = diff > 0 ? pad(tmp, diff).split('').join('.') : num;
var pattern = '#\{padded\}';
var regEx = new RegExp(pattern , 'g');
return tmpl.replace(regEx, padded);
}

var button = document.getElementById('submit');
button.addEventListener('click', processArea);

function processArea() {
var area = document.getElementById('area');
var arr = area.value.split(/\n/);
var header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist   
SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">\n<plist 
version="1.0">\n<dict>\n<array>\n';
var footer = '\n</array>\n</plist>';
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  arr[i] = processString(arr[i]);
}
area.value = header+arr.join('\r\n')+footer;
}

/*console.log(fill('1.1'));
console.log(fill('1.1.2'));
console.log(fill('1.1.3.4'));
console.log(fill('1'));*/
```

Comment: for more clarity you can view this fiddle.

my answer works.

http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/21/